# alternative to GrantedAuthorityImpl() class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want an alternative to GrantedAuthorityImpl() class. I want this in spring security implementation. GrantedAuthorityImpl() class is deprecated. Hence I want an alternative solution to it.
My code :

```
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer access) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);
    
    if (access.compareTo(1) == 0) {
        authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }
    else{
        authList.add(new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    return authList;
}
```

Comment: Spring Security Ver  3.1.3

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The class GrantedAuthorityImpl has been deprecated - you can use SimpleGrantedAuthority instead:

```
public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Integer access) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(2);

    if (access.compareTo(1) == 0) {
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
    }
    else{
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
    }
    return authList;
}
```